# Rename multiple files using ftp

Tags: ftp, rename

I have a set of files in my ftp folder. I have access to only ftp mode. I want to rename those files with extension .txt to .done

Ex:

```
1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt
```

to

```
1.done, 2.done, 3.done
```

Only rename command is working in this ftp. I am expecting something like

```
rename *.txt *.done
```

to rename them all  in a single command.

Comment: could you pls help me with a sample small script?

Answer (score 3):

In short: You can't.
FTP is very basic and does not support mass renaming. You can either write a small script for it, or download some helper software, such as [the one here](http://www.smartftp.com/features/bulkrename/).

Comment: could you pls help me with a sample small script?

Comment: Which OS are you on? And, why not use smartftp?

Answer (score 1):

Hallo to all,

Even if the question is quite old, I think could be usefull for others to read my suggestion.

I found a great and easy solution combining [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/), "A FTP filesystem based on cURL and FUSE" as they define it, and [rename](https://www.linux.com/news/rename-command-line-tool-renaming-multiple-files-linux) linux and unix multi rename tool.

I tested on linux mint 17 (and I think it should work in other debian based distributions)

1. install curlftpfs

   ```
   sudo apt-get install curlftpfs
   ```
2. create the mount folder

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/ftp_remote_root
   ```
3. mount remote ftp on folder

   ```
   sudo curlftpfs -o allow_other -o user="USERWITH@CHARACTERTOO:PASSWORDTOACCESSUSER" ftp://my_ftp_server.com /mnt/ftp_remote_root/
   ```
4. jump into desired ftp remote folder

   ```
   cd /mnt/ftp_remote_root/path/to/folder
   ```
5. rename as you need files (-v shw new names, -n show interested files, omitt them to rename files)

   ```
   sudo rename -v -n 's/match.regexp/replace.regexp/' *.file.to.change
   ```

It could took few seconds because it works on network.

I think it is really powerfull and easy to use.

Let me know if you find any problems.

Bye

Lorenzo

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

#### the following example move/rename files on the FTP server

> for f in $(lftp -u 'username,password' -e 'set ssl:verify-certificate
>   no; ls /TEST/src/*.csv; quit' ftp.acme.com| awk '{print $9;}'); do
>   lftp -u 'username,password' -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no; mv
>   /TEST/src/$f /TEST/dst/$f; quit" ftp.acme.com; done

note: use .netrc to store username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

ren *.txt *.done